# How to uglify / minify PHP output?

Tags: javascript, php, gruntjs

I know the output generated by PHP will follow the way my code is written. For instance :

```
echo '<div id="test">';
echo '<div id="other-test>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Will output something like

```
<div id="test">
<div id="other-test">
</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to generate something like this instead, without change my code ?

```
<div id="test"><div id="other-test"></div></div>;
```

Would be something like grunt do with .js files.

I know i could change my source code to get this output, but this would make the code harder to read during developing.

Why i want to do this ? Because if i open the source of html output of my app, i see a lot of line breaks and blank spaces and i think if i could get ride of it, less network traffic would be required.

Thanks !

Comment: I think you mean "minify"? That might help you find something.

Comment: Yes, minify ; i just used 'uglify' because this is the term in Grunt's 'uglify' module. Thanks for the hint, i've edited the title.

Comment: @Teemu The example above is just a a very simple situation to explain the point ; the real problem happens when generating datagrids for large tables, for instance. If i had to put all code in one line, it would be impossible to debug.

Comment: @Teemu yes, but my source code has more than a hundred lines ; as i said, i could get the output i want if i put everything in a single line, but imagine debugging it...

Comment: Enabling caching + gzip will probably yield much better results compared to processing html in your php code before each response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use output buffering.  You've got something like this

```
<?php
echo '<div id="test">';
echo '<div id="other-test>';
//a lot of other complicated output logic

echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

First, at the start of your code add a call to start output buffering.  This will prevent PHP from sending output.

```
<?php
ob_start();    
echo '<div id="test">';
echo '<div id="other-test>';
//a lot of other complicated output logic    
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Then, at the end of the long complicated output code, use `ob_get_clean()`

```
<?php    
ob_start();    
echo '<div id="test">';
echo '<div id="other-test>';
//a lot of other complicated output logic    
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';    

$output = ob_get_clean();
```

The call to `ob_get_clean` will discard the output buffer (PHP won't echo anything) but return the contents of the output buffer before doing so (i.e. `$output` will have a string of what would have been output).

You're then free to modify the the string all you like before `echo`ing it yourself

```
<?php    
ob_start();    
echo '<div id="test">';
echo '<div id="other-test>';
//a lot of other complicated output logic    
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';    

$output = ob_get_clean();

//remove newlines and carriage returns
$output = str_replace("\r", '', $output);            
$output = str_replace("\n", '', $output);                
$output = someOtherMinifyFunction($output);
echo $output;
```

Comment: Does PHP really end `echo` with  `\r\n`?

Comment: @Loïc -- No, PHP's echo doesn't add any carriage returns or linefeeds -- for the sake of this question assume those are added in the `//a lot of other complicated output logic` section.

Comment: This worked, thanks ! I just don't know the impact generated due the processing power needed to do this, but the generated code is a LOT smaller :)

Comment: @delphirules Impact is negligible on modern hardware -- you'll hit performance problems on other things waaaaaaay sooner.